# Detecting an update to a global var in async function

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I'm having trouble updating a variable to the global scope. I have declared a variable *state*, then when a function is complete I return the variable. This all works. However I have another function running asynchronously where I'm waiting for the var to update, but it never gets the updated *state* value and loops 'notReady' indefinitely. I expected "return state" to update the variable in the global scope but it doesn't. How can I get the updated global *state* variable to update in a previously fired function?

```
var state = 'notReady';

function do(state){
   // long/heavy webGL function
   state = 'ready'
   return state; //state successfully changes to 'ready'
};

$.when( do(state) ).then(function(state) {
    console.log(state); // this logs 'ready' successfully
    return state;
});


function previousFiredFunction(){
   function waitForState(){
      if(state === 'ready'){
         // do something when ready (this is never 'ready')
      } else {
         setTimeout(waitForState, 200); 
      }
   }
   waitForState();
}
previousFiredFunction();
```

Comment: `typeof state === 'ready'` this will never be true, because `'ready'` is not a valid value for a `typeof`. Guessing your `typeof` shouldn't be there?

Comment: ok, thanks. I overlooked that, yeah it shouldn't be there, but when deleted I'm still getting the old state in console in the else, where the setTimeout is, so it's still not getting the update. (edited code to remove typeof)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `do` function, you have a function argument with the same name as your global variable (`state`). This masks the global variable. And all "native" variables (e.g. strings and numbers) are passed by value, NOT by reference.

Simple fix, just lose the argument entirely. Then you will be working with the global variable.

```
var state = 'notReady';

function fndo() {
  // long/heavy webGL function
  state = 'ready'
  return state; //state successfully changes to 'ready'
};

$.when(fndo(state)).then(function (state) {
  console.log(state); // this logs 'ready' successfully
  return state;
});


function previousFiredFunction() {
  function waitForState() {
    console.log('wfs', state);
    if (state === 'ready') {
      // do something when ready (this is never 'ready')
    } else {
      setTimeout(waitForState, 200);
    }
  }
  waitForState();
}
previousFiredFunction();
```

Also as an aside, I'm really surprised you can get this code to run at all, since `do` is a [keyword in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while). I had to change the name to even run your code.

Comment: That that's it! I thought I ruled that out. As an aside do() isn't actually the name of my function, but good catch.